# Specificity between not() and first-child selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

So we have the following example about `not()` and `p:first-child{}` selectors.Here is the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p:first-child{
color: red;
}
p:not(a){
    color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Why the paragraph is red at the end? Can somebody explain (if possible ) why the  `p:first-child{}` has bigger specificity than `not()` selector???

Comment: I'm not sure how this should behave, but it's illogical to say `if x is not x` how can a tag selector become another tag? I changed this to a class and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/jncwLrhr/

Comment: @Aziz interestingly `p:not(a)` has higher specificity than `p`, even though logically it could be shortcutted. I think what it is is that `:not()` has a specificity based on its sub-selector. Would have to call up the spec to confirm `p:not(a)` is just a slightly more specific tag selector.

Comment: @abluejelly: _“interestingly `p:not(a)` has higher specificity than `p`”_ – that’s because the first one contains _two_ element selectors, whereas the last one only one – so it’s `0-0-0-2` vs `0-0-0-1`.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah that's 'cause the initial assumption based on what Aziz said was `p:not(a)` was being shortcutted to `p` since the selector `:not()` was being applied to can never match the notted content. Which shows it's not simply being shortcutted. Something that disproves an assumption is interesting.

Comment: @abluejelly yeah, of course it is not “shortcutted”. If I say about a person, they are a human being, then I have described them by one attribute; if I say that they are a human being and they are not a unicorn, then I have described them by _two_ attributes – that one of those attributes is a “negative” one doesn’t affect the _count_ of course.

Comment: @abluejelly: That's right. The specificity of a selector is not influenced by its meaning. As far as specificity is concerned, `p:not(a)` (matching any p) is no different from `p:not(p)` (matching *nothing*) or `body p` (matching any p in an HTML document, but potentially behaving differently elsewhere) or `p::before` (a pseudo-elt is equally specific to a tagname). Similarly, `[id=foo]` has the specificity of an attribute selector, not an id selector, because Selectors doesn't assume that the id attribute maps to an "ID-typed" attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can somebody explain (if possible ) why the  p:first-child{} has bigger specificity than not() selector?

Because :not() doesn’t have any influence on specificity itself – only what is inside it counts in regard to specificity.

So you have the element selector `p` and the pseudo class `:first-child`, which gives a specificity of `0-0-1-1` – and you have the element selectors `p` and `a`, which result in `0-0-0-2`.

Comment: Have a [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity). "Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other, but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class."

Comment: Really? You're going to question why I provided the link to where in the specification it says that you're correct, and the exact quote from the spec that states you're correct?

Comment: On one hand, you really need to work on contextualized reading comprehension. On the other, there probably are people on this site that will not emphasize that they're saying something's wrong with your post when they toss a spec at you, and you've been around long enough to have unfortunately met them. So I'm gonna go with "y-you too".

Comment: This conversation made my day.