# Why is a difference between inline CSS and normal CSS

Tags: css, inline-styles

I did just want to answer a question  and I fall on something I dont understand!
Why the result is not the same if I use inline CSS or CSS in a file like the color in this case!

The code is the same but the 1st paragraph is green and the 2nd red!

I really dont understand why?

Thank you

```html
<head>
 <style>
p:first-child{
color: red;
}
p:not(a){
color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This a paragraph.</p>

</body>
```

```css
p:first-child{
color: red;
}
p:not(a){
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>This a paragraph.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: In the first example the HTML isn't valid. The `style` tags should be in the `head`.

Comment: What is `p:not(a)`? `p` cannot be `a`, and it's neither a class nor id.

Comment: If you look at the node tree in dev tools, in your first example the style tag is moved within the body tag meaning that `p` is no longer the first child

Comment: or more accurately, the `body` tags are being stripped from you code.

Comment: This example was just used in a question minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610048/specificity-between-not-and-first-child-selectors and it was answered.

Comment: Technically what you're showing here is more like in-file CSS, in-line generally refers to where you include a style attribute on the HTML element itself. e.g. `<p style="color:#000"></p>` (And is generally frowned upon, as it's messy and hard to maintain)

Comment: Thanks to all of you because of you I learned something today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy your first snippet into a file and open it in a browser the paragraph is indeed red as in the second example.

But for some strange reason* if you run the first snippet *in* stackoverflow the style element is moved *into* the body element before the p element (just introspect with firebug). Now p is not the first child and therefore the red-color rule does not apply.

*EDIT: or not that strange (see comment by Turnip) since the body tag is stripped from the script.

Comment: Oh yes in FIDDLE it is the same thank you I really was surprised when I saw that

Answer (score 1):

`p:first-child` will only render on the first child if it is a `p` tag. For whatever reason, the StackOverflow snippet is rendering the code as:

```
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <style type="text/css"></style></head>
  <body>
    <style>
      p:first-child{
        color: red;
      }
      p:not(a){
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
    <p>This a paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first child is the `<style>` tag, which got moved into the body. Because of this, there is no `p:first-child` and so the color red never renders, this leaves green as the only style applied to the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

While there is [an exception for the `:not()` pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_not_exception)  in the [CSS Specificity Rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) that determine when specific CSS styles are applied to certain elements, the real issue here is a matter of invalid markup.

The first example that you provided is actually invalid as `<style>` blocks must be declared within the `<head>` element [according to the spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#the-style-element), and you'll notice when this is corrected the results should be the same:

[image]

**Doh!** Or it's just a matter of Stack Overflow's editor stripping out the `<body>` tags within the code examples per the comment from [Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746736/turnip).